# Test ALL rows exists

Tags: sql, exists

It is very simple to test when row exists or not.

```
if exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw=@zestaw)
```

I want to test in my query whether **all rows** satisfy the condition.

I need use some query like this

```
if All exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw=@zestaw and type=3)
```

But this syntax is not correct.

Comment: select count and check greater than 0?

Comment: Which of these do you mean?  `All rows must have both (zestaw=@zestaw) and (type=3)` or do you mean `All rows that have (zestaw=@zestaw) must have (type=3)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
if NOT exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw<>@zestaw OR type<>3) 
  --all rows satisfy the condition
```

if your columns can be nullable, then

```
if NOT exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw<>@zestaw OR type<>3) 
AND NOT exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw IS NULL OR type IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

This may perform better than an OR because it keep the AND and uses semi-joins

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT zestaw, [type] FROM #foo
   EXCEPT
   SELECT zestaw, [type] FROM #foo where zestaw=@zestaw and type=3
   )
  -- all rows etc
```

Edit, quick and dirty test (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on workstation), the EXCEPT uses more IO (2 touches) but less CPU (more efficient plan)

If you replace `@zestaw` with a constant, the NOT EXISTS .. OR .. wins

```
CREATE TABLE excepttest (zestaw int, [type] int);
INSERT excepttest VALUES (1, 3);
GO
INSERT excepttest SELECT excepttest.* FROM excepttest
GO 21
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM excepttest
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_Test ON excepttest (zestaw, [type]);
GO

DECLARE @zestaw int = 1;
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
if NOT exists(select * from excepttest where zestaw<>@zestaw OR [type]<>3) 
   SELECT 'all match'
ELSE
   SELECT 'some match';

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT zestaw, [type] FROm excepttest
        EXCEPT
        SELECT zestaw, [type] FROm excepttest where zestaw=@zestaw and [type]=3
        )
   SELECT 'all match'
ELSE
   SELECT 'some match';

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
DROP TABLE excepttest
```

Comment: @OlegDok: ran a test, mixes results

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the conditions in the WHERE clause **and** the whole `exists` expression:

```
if NOT exists select(select * from dbo.APQP_head where zestaw <> @zestaw OR type <> 3)
```

This uses a well known fact that NOT(A1 AND A2 AND ... An) == NOT(A1) OR NOT(A2)... OR NOT(An).

Comment: Thank you all! I expected simple answer. I have specific @zestaw and I want to know that it hasn't type different than 3. So I will test: not exist (select * from APQPhead where zestaw=@zestaw and type<>3)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
if not exists(select * from dbo.APQP_head where not (zestaw=@zestaw and type=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution for some problems:

```
select distinct AccAccountId from AccAccountTafsilType where AccAccountId 
in (select Id From AccountForSooratVaziatFunc(5))
and AccAccountId in (select AccAccountId from AccAccountTafsilType where 
TafsilTypeId in (select Id from AccTafsilType where ComplexId = 5 and 
Code = 115))
and AccAccountId in (select AccAccountId from AccAccountTafsilType where 
TafsilTypeId in (select Id from AccTafsilType where ComplexId = 5 and 
Code = 116))
```